# Check node version and include dependencies accordingly

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

By Any chance is there anyway to check, node version and add dependencies accordingly.
For example in SPA, How I can check if node version-8, then during NPM install refer to "package-name":"8.0.1"

1. IF Node Version 10, then NPM INSTALL should refer to "package-name":"10.0.1"
2. If Node version 8, then NPM INSTALL should refer to "package-name":"8.0.1"

Comment: Simplest way is to use package.json for all dependency in projects.

Comment: I am not sure why you got 3 downvotes for this.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I was also wondering. actually its a valid question and I'm struggling to optimise this process in my project.

Answer (score 2):

NPM supports an [`engines`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) field in `package.json`. For example:

```js
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=10.3 <12" } }
```

Means that a package works on Node versions higher than 10.3 and lower than 12. When NPM performs package resolution it will attempt to use that field and resolve packages for you.

You can define your own package `anup-dep-installer` and publish two versions of it - one for Node 8 and one for Node 10 (specify the engines field). When you NPM install it it should pick the right one correctly.

Note that you shouldn't have to do this if the packages specify this automatically - and it is an extremely bad idea to include different packages on different node versions normally for anything other than compatibility reasons.

Comment: Yes @Benjamin - its due to compatibility reason only.

Comment: So, how will I refer dependency in package.json, i.e How will I specify version number In package.json. I already have multiple version for NODE8 "8.0.1" , Node10 "10.0.1", Node12 "12.0.1"